# PostgreSQL - Python - Trigger - Access to current_user

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, triggers, plpython

I am writing an audit trigger in plPython. I cannot figure out how to get access to the current_user variable. Is it available via plpy somehow?

I would also like to know if it is possible to pass variables into a trigger function? If so how is this done? I tried:

```
create trigger stock_sys_audit before insert or update or delete on stock_tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE sys_audit(current_user);
```

but it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an access to all Postgres functions and settings only via SQL. Use [`plpy.execute(),`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html#idm46046859142368) example:

```
create or replace function py_current_user()
returns text language plpython3u
as $$
    res = plpy.execute("select current_user")
    return res[0]["current_user"]
$$;

select py_current_user();

 py_current_user 
-----------------
 postgres
(1 row)
```